# When opening 2 of 35 SSIS packages in Visual Studio I get error popup see error list. Error lists all connections from dtsconfig not in package. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I don't understand why 2 of my 35 or so SSIS packages throw connection errors when opening package in Visual Studio.  All packages configure from same dtsconfig and no package contains all the connections in dtsconfig but 33 of them don't throw the error pop up and don't list connections that couldn't be found in the package.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: What is the protection level for the packages that fail as compared with those that don't? Similarly, how do the connection strings compare?

Comment: Same.  Don't save sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I did not figure out why some packages gave hard errors that others didn't but resolved by changing the way I made connections.

Previously connection strings were in .dtsconfig as:

```
`<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property"
```

Path="\Package.Connections[D01_VISN05].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String"> Data Source=VHACDWDWHSQL33;Initial Catalog=D01_VISN05;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-TH-V5DW;Trust Server Certificate=True; `

I changed to setting variables in .dtsconfig and then setting the package connection property/expression to use the variable.

Connection Property Expression:
`@[User::ConnStringD01_VISN05_OLEDB]`

.dtsconfig:
`

```
          <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=VHACDWDWHSQL33.vha.med.va.gov;Initial Catalog=D01_VISN05;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Packet Size=32767;</ConfiguredValue>

   </Configuration>
`
```

Comment: Sorry I can't get format to show code block properly.  It's stripping out a couple lines of code.